# JS how to set an object to eval as content?

Tags: javascript, eval

I need a simple js engine.
So, i created a function:

```
  function compile(tpl, scope){
    return tpl.replace(/\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g, function(caught, content){
      var compiled;
      try{
        compiled = eval.call(scope, content);
      }catch(e){
        compiled = caught;
        console.error(e);
      }finally{
        return compiled;
      }
    });
  }
```

Okay, invoke it.

```
    compile('<div>{{ maxSize / 1024 / 1024 }}M</div>', { maxSize: 1048576 });
```

But, an error jump out **"maxSize is not defined"**.

How can i solve it?

Comment: You can't pass an object as variable scope. `eval` will take its enclosing scope.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may probably help is to use another evil construction [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) and do something like that:

```
try {
    compiled = (new Function('with(this){return ' + content + '}')).call(scope);
} catch ( ... )
```

This will make your approach work, however won't make it safe.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4rujz5b7/

Comment: Good idea to use `with`.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm in strict mode

Comment: @gordomium: So what? The compiled function isn't.